# wrap returned value in transaction

Tags: clojure

It seems to me that what I want to achieve is trivial; nevertheless it gives me quite some headaches to figure it out on my own.

I have a service implementation written in Clojure which speaks to a Database backend via JPA.
I have to do something like this:

```
(defn foo []
  (let [entitymanager ... query ...]
    (do
      (.. entitymanager (getTransaction) (begin))
      (read-from-db query) ; <-- shall be returned
      (.. entitymanager (getTransaction) (commit))
      )
    )
  )
```

with *read-from-db* returning a value. I looked into the *java.jdbc* package and it looks promising but I want to/have to stick to the JPA. Furthermore, my problem seems not to be specific to the JPA per sé.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this kind of wrapping of the return value in Clojure? 
Please bear in mind I am a Clojure novice.

Kind regards!

Comment: Are you just asking for a way to return the value of (read-from-db-query) *after* performing the commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure to understand your issue. Here is my answer on what I guess is your issue:

```
(defn foo []
  (let [entitymanager ... query ...]
    (do
      (.. entitymanager (getTransaction) (begin))
      (let [db-reply (read-from-db query)] ; <-- shall be returned
        (.. entitymanager (getTransaction) (commit))
        db-reply)
      )
    )
  )
```

Correct?

Comment: Yes ofc! I thought about wrapping it with a _let_, but having it sequentially in a single let gave me a strange behavior regarding the order of execution - that should do it! Thanks!

Comment: I find this pattern comes up often enough that it's useful to have a function analogous to Common Lisp's `prog1` shoved in a utility library somewhere.